# How to check if two polygons intersect in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

How can I check if two polygons intersect in PG 8.3?

`#` and `#?` don't work for polygons:

```
select polygon'((0,0), (1,2), (0,2))' # polygon'((0.5, 0), (1,0), (1,1))';
ERROR:  operator does not exist: polygon # polygon

select polygon'((0,0), (1,2), (0,2))' #? polygon'((0.5, 0), (1,0), (1,1))';
ERROR:  operator does not exist: polygon #? polygon
```

And `&&` gives wrong asnwer:

```
select polygon'((0,0), (1,2), (0,2))' && polygon'((0.5, 0), (1,0), (1,1))';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Wow! Version 9.0 gives the correct answer, false, but 8.4 (and your 8.3) give the wrong answer. Looks like a bug to me. You'd better submit a bugreport at http://www.postgresql.org/support/submitbug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue with pre-9 Postgres: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2011-02/msg00139.php